# Shopify: Can you call the OAUTH2 permission URL without requesting additional permissions?

Tags: shopify

The Shopify documentation states:

> Requesting access to a shop with no additional permissions beyond the basics:
>
> https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=API_KEY

Source: *http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth*

However when you actually try this, you are redirected to your login-finalize URL with an error, "invalid scope".

> ```
> www.mydomain.com/shopify/login/finalize/?error=invalid_scope&shop=<redacted>.myshopify.com&timestamp=1365220455&signature=<redacted>
> ```

It seems that the documentation contradicts the implementation here, so my question is: How can I call the OAUTH2 permission URL without requesting additional permissions beyond the basics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid not. Need one scope at a minimum. I just use the read_products as my 'default' scope.

You can see full info here. http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/scope-parameter-in-auth-reqs-132941

Comment: Yeah thanks. If anyone from Shopify reads this it seems the API docs are just plain wrong at point 5. Examples, here: http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth